# Why doesn't this work in VSCode terminal?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, zsh, python-decorators, vscode-debugger

I've been trying to see if I'm making a silly mistake on this very small class but it seems to be a problem with VSCode.

```
#planetoids.py
from collections import namedtuple

Vector2D = namedtuple("Vector2D", ['x', 'y'])

class Player:

    def __init__(self, coords):
        self._pos = Vector2D(*coords)

    @property
    def pos(self):
        return self._pos

    @pos.setter
    def pos(self, coords):
        self._pos = Vector2D(*coords)
```

```
#test_planetoids.py
import unittest
import planetoids

class TestPlayer(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.player = planetoids.Player([2,3])

    def test_has_pos(self):
        self.assertTrue(hasattr(self.player, "pos"))
        pos = self.player.pos
        self.assertTrue(hasattr(pos, 'x'))
        self.assertTrue(hasattr(pos, 'y'))

    def test_maintains_pos(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.player.pos.x, 2)
        self.assertEqual(self.player.pos.y, 3)
        self.player.pos = [7,9]
        self.test_has_pos()
        self.assertEqual(self.player.pos.x, 7)
        self.assertEqual(self.player.pos.y, 9)
```

In Visual Studio Code both tests pass in the debugger, but one fails when I run normally.

Some print statements reveal that when I run test_planetoids in terminal, `self.player.pos = [7,9]` assigns the list to pos as if I hadn't written a pos setter. But when I set a breakpoint, it goes right to the setter as expected.
I tried running it in IDLE, and all three tests pass.

Is this code unstable in some way that makes it have unpredictable behavior? If not, what VSCode configurations or terminal configurations might cause this?

I'm not sure I want to switch to IDLE as a development environment because it has fewer features, but this is quite problematic.

Edit: The error output as requested. I will say I think the output is somewhat misleading. Like I said earlier, it arises because the list is passed directly.

```
.F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_maintains_pos (__main__.TestPlayer)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_planetoids.py", line 19, in test_maintains_pos
    self.test_has_pos()
  File "test_planetoids.py", line 12, in test_has_pos
    self.assertTrue(hasattr(pos, 'x'))
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Edit2: I got VSCode to do this for another class. Apparently Vector2D(*list_with_2_elements) is either unreliable or in conflict with some configuration of my VSCode or my machine I'm unaware of.

Comment: Please add the error output to the question!

Comment: Probably not your problem, but both asserttrue in test_maintains_pos should probably be assertequal.

Comment: why do you duplicate the setter code in the constructor

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson thanks, corrected but yes not the problem

Comment: @KlausD. I added it

Comment: @rioV8 what would you suggest as an alternative? I was simply following examples.

Comment: just as an FYI, I ran your code in VS Code on Ubuntu in a virtualenv using `Python 3.6.9` and tests passed without issue. I ran it by using `if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()` *EDIT* Did a quick test in `Python 3.9.5` and it ran as well... *EDIT2* running the test using `python -m unittest test_planetoids.py` worked as well

Comment: why don't you use the property

Comment: @rioV8 Not sure what you mean, could you maybe type the line?

Comment: @EdoAkse so maybe it is something with my particular vscode but idk what

Comment: @EdoAkse I'm on 3.9.1 btw but it shouldn't matter because it worked everywhere else with the same version

Comment: @EdoAkse aha I think you uncovered something. When I tried the ```python -m unittest test_planetoids.py``` I got some output talking about some Python 2 frameworks. I tried ```python3 -m unittest test_planetoids.py``` and it worked great. So I think the problem is that "python" is linked to python2.

Comment: this is why you should always use a virtualenv

Comment: @rioV8 I see what you mean, I replaced it. I wanted to reduce the usage of it to try and isolate the problem.

Comment: @ThoughtOfGod : Why is this tagged as zsh?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is standard for macOS, but "python" is linked to Python 2.
The VSCode debugger used the Python 3 interpreter, but when I executed the test alone using `python test_planetoids.py` it executed in Python 2.

The solution in this case is to use `python3 test_planetoids.py`